# Vue: standard way to hide template if no data or loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've got a Vue component for Google Maps that looks like this:

```
Vue.component('user-map', {
  template: '<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md col-lg-8"> \
    <gmap-map style="width: 630px; height: 200px" :center="coords" :zoom="13"> \
      <gmap-marker :position="coords"></gmap-marker> \
    </gmap-map> \
  </div>',
  data: function () {
    return {
      coords: {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getCoords(window._client_code)
  },
  methods: {
    getCoords: function (clientCode) {
      this.$http.get(`${window.location.origin}/share/${clientCode}/map`)
          .then(response => {
        this.coords = response.body[0]
      }, response => {
        console.log('no coords')
      })
    }
  },
  computed: {
    finalLat: function() {
      return this.coords.lat
    },
    finalLng: function() {
      return this.coords.lng
    }
  }
})
```

How can I hide the template while it's loading the JSON response or if the response is null?

Comment: try:`<gmap-map v-if="coords">`

Comment: There is no "standard" way. That being said, you could do something as simple as a `v-if` checking whether or not `coords` has any data, and possibly a `v-else` if you want to display an alternative view while no data is being display (e.g. v-if="coords").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a data field that gets set true/false on loading success, and `v-show` or `v-if` off that on `<gmap-map />`. I want to say most of the Vue UI frameworks I've seen just use a variable or computed that's true or false (Element uses 'loading')